# Default Jekyll install Ubuntu not rewriting .js extensions

Tags: jekyll

I have many posts that I write as example.js files with the proper yaml front matter. In Jekyll 2.5.1 these get changed to example.html. My permalink in the config is /:title.html. In the latest version installed by running gem install jekyll in Ubuntu, I believe version 3.1.3, these posts get renamed to example.html.js.

Ideas?

For now I am just using version 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your permalink by `/:basename.html`.

Comment: jekyll new blog, change the test post extension to .js, change permalink settings in config to /:title.html, /:slug.html, /:basename.html. The first two result in "welcome-to-jekyll.html.js", /:basename.html results in an error. If you set the permalink in the post yaml itself to /:title.html or /:slug.html it works. However, I need to be able to set this in the config file.

Posting an issue on github as well.

Comment: It's a Jekyll issue, not a github one.